# ExtJs JSONStore loaddata method loading only single record

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to load data in JSONStore using loadData method, but it is only loading single record in store. Here is code snippet

```
var myRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
    {
        name: 'Rid',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'id.value'
    }, {
        name: 'accountId',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'accountId.value'
    }, {
        name: 'nickName',
        type: 'string'
    }
]);

var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'storeID',
        fields: myRecord,           
        root: 'recipientResponse',
        autoLoad: false

});

myStore.loadData(jsonResponse,true);
```

Here is sample JSON response that I am passing to loadData method

```
{ recipientResponse: [
    {
        "id":{
            "value":"58144340bedf4a328669c98b29446b6b"
        },
        "locked":null,
        "accountId":{
            "type":null,
            "value":"1122334455"
        },
        "nickName":"Dad",
        "customerId":{
            "value":"partialpay7"
        },
        "accountType":"CHECKING", 
        "emailAddress":"blah@blah.com",
        "person":null,
        "deleted":null,
        "txPasscode":"Cho"
     },
     {
        "id":{
            "value":"5fb1e201a939433faea6c39e33caef78"
        },
        "locked":null,
        "accountId":{
            "type":null,
            "value":"6655223311"
        },
        "nickName":"Jane Doe",
        "customerId":{
            "value":"partialpay7"
        },
        "accountType":"CHECKING",
        "emailAddress":"blah@blah.com",
        "person":null,
        "deleted":null,
        "txPasscode":"Cho"
     },
     {
        "id":{
             "value":"a24b32fd180e4886b1f562d9a3b2f0ce"
        },
        "locked":null,
        "accountId":{
            "type":null,
            "value":"998877665544"
        },
        "nickName":"Sam Jones",
        "customerId":{
            "value":"partialpay7"
        },
        "accountType":"CHECKING",
        "emailAddress":"blah@blah.com",
        "person":null,
        "deleted":null,
        "txPasscode":"Cho"
     }
]}
```

Thanks

Comment: is the problem that only the last record shows up in the end ? seems that having {value:string} as the key for the record requires slightly more work, but trying to make sure I got the problem down.

Comment: what ExtJS version do you use?

Comment: @AbrahamAdam - Yes always last record shows up in the store

Comment: The reason I am responding this late is since I need to get this done soon, I dropped idea of loading this in store and used JSON object as is. But loading it in store would have helped me. I would still like to know root cause so that I can use this is future.

Comment: @sagar Does that mean that setting `idProperty: 'Rid'` didn't help? I had made some tests with your code as a base and got it working, so I was pretty sure about my answer...

Comment: @rixo I am going to write similar code today, since there is another case where I need to load same object in a store. I will let you know by tomorrow. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 6):

You must configure the [`idProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader-cfg-idProperty).

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    storeId: 'storeID',
    fields: myRecord,           
    root: 'recipientResponse',
    autoLoad: false,
    idProperty: 'Rid'
});
```

If you don't, it defaults to 'id', so the json reader use your whole objects `{id: ...}` as id. In the end, these ids are used as keys in the data collection, and they all cast to the same string like "[object Object]". Here's why.

Comment: Let me try this out, will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jsonResponse it's a Object/Array or String ?

It's a String, try using:

```
myStore.loadData(Ext.JSON.encode(jsonResponse),true);
```

Sencha: [JSON Encode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.JSON-method-encode)

Comment: Its not a String, its proper JSON object.

Comment: Ext.data.JsonStore :: NOTE This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework. Don't rely on its existence. (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore) Try use **Ext.data.Store** (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

Comment: @mfruizs2 He's probably not using Ext4, but Ext3.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to use **loadRawData** NOT **loadData**?